# Is there any authoritative source from where we can find out if a phrase or figure of speech is American English or British English?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, figures-of-speech

For example the figure of speech " One swallow doesn't make a summer" is British English. Similarly the figure of speech 'All hat and no cattle" is American English.

Is there any source from where we can find out if the phrase or figure of speech is American or British?

Comment: Apparently, *one swallow does not a summer make* comes from [a remark by Aristotle (384 BCE - 322 BCE)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make), so it predates even the English language, let alone the discovery of America.

Comment: It's called the internet. The problem with your request is that it is impractical. Some figures of speech are used in both countries. Not only that but some figures of speech are used only  in *part* of Britain or *part*  of America.

Comment: "Some figures of speech are used in both countries"  Some are, but there are several that are not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources.

Comment: Off topic, why? The rules section of this community clearly states that questions related to Dialects can be asked http://english.stackexchange.com/tour     A phrase is a dialect coz  it is a regional or social variety of a language

Comment: Re "request for resources" I am not sure how you define this term in this context , but I found several questions in this community that are on similar lines. For example http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76479/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-capitalisation-rules-for-pure-british-writing?rq=1

Comment: @D_S: _I found several questions in this community that are on similar lines. For example english.stackexchange.com/questions/76479/_  ... There is a major difference between this question and the one linked to: the other one asks a question that can be directly answered. This one only asks for resources. Questions on dialects are ok, but asking for resources for dialects is no different from any other such request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of anything that would directly answer such questions, but maybe you could do it by process of elimination using as a resource the reference work ***[Dictionary of American Regional English](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674205116)***, a four-volume work that attempts to collect Americanisms.