# A swallow does not make a summer ..... or a spring?

Tags: etymology, expressions, proverbs

The famous proverb, ***[one swallow does not make a summer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-swallow-does-not-make-a-summer)***  means:

> - A single fortunate event doesn’t mean that what follows will also be good.
>     (ODO)

the origin, according to the  Phrase Finder:

> - This old proverb is listed in several early glossaries, notably Richard Taverner's transcription of the [Latin] proverbs of Erasmus - Prouerbes or adagies with newe addicions, gathered out of the Chiliades of Erasmus, 1539:
>
>   - *It is not one swalowe that bryngeth in somer. It is not one good qualitie that maketh a man good.*

The same proverb is very popular also in ***France and [Italy](http://www.paginainizio.com/genio/perch%C3%A9-si-dice-che-una-rondine-non-fa-primavera.html)*** where the version is "***a swallow does not make a spring"*** and its origin is said to be  from  Aristotle “Etica Nicomachea” where the philosopher says:

> - "One swallow does not a summer make, nor one fine day; similarly one day or brief time of happiness does not make a person entirely happy"

According to  [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=does%20not%20make%20a%20%20summer%2Cdoes%20not%20make%20a%20spring%2Cdoes%20not%20a%20summer%20make&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20make%20a%20summer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20make%20a%20spring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20a%20summer%20make%3B%2Cc0) also the "spring" version appears to be  used, but most references  cite only the "summer" one.

Questions:

- Which is the more common version in AmE and BrE.
- Why did the "summer" version become common usage despite the  common notion that swallows make their appearence during spring, not during summer.
- Was the Middle English term "somer" a broader concept in terms of  seasons compared to the modern one? If so, is this the origin of the "misunderstanding" of the proverb" ?

Comment: Interesting! According to the following question, the expression is used more in British English: [Is there any authoritative source from where we can find out if a phrase or figure of speech is American English or British English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266714/is-there-any-authoritative-source-from-where-we-can-find-out-if-a-phrase-or-figu) I think I've read something about the concept of "spring" as a season being more recent than "summer" and "winter" (and "fall" used to just be called harvest(time)).

Comment: @sumelic: The idea there were only two seasons, winter and summer, seems to have lasted in England in popular culture at least until the song [Summer Is Icumen In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumer_Is_Icumen_In) was composed. (Look at the lyrics. They describe Spring.) This is generally believed to have been in the 13th century. So the question is: how old is the saying *"One swallow does not a summer make."* Since [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make) credits it to Aristotle, one can certainly imagine it being used during Middle English.

Comment: The first solitary swallow sighting near the Mediterranean is quite likely to be a premature migrant as (many species of) birds cross at fairly narrow routes when the weather is favourable and so appear together. In Britain, apart from the transit time (and swallows fly quite fast), unless you're near a nesting site your first swallow of the year is likely to be an early breeder catching insects on a warm spring day that feels like but isn't summer. This isn't to disagree with @PeterShor but to suggest a pressure to stick with "summer" as the words drift in meaning.

Comment: I've never heard the version with "spring" in Britain.

Comment: @PeterShor - that is an interesting point, but the term and the concept of "spring" appear to be quite old too: 
*season following winter, the vernal season, c. 1400, earlier springing time (late 14c.), which replaced Lent, the Old English word. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spring

Comment: @ChrisH - the "spring" version does not look so uncommon in BrE according to google books: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=does+not+make+a+spring&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20make%20a%20spring%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 without "swallow" (which makes it too long) "does not make a spring" is useless. E.g. "does not make a spring day warm/pleasant/wet", "does not make a spring stiffer/more flexible", "does not make a spring run dry". Each could be individually vanishingly rare but with "spring" having so many meanings and everything else common they all add up. However it's perfectly possible that I've just been in the wrong place at the wrong time to hear (or remember) the "swallow...spring" version.

Comment: @Chris H - you are right, but if you check inside most instances refer to the proverb.

Comment: @josh61: The old Anglo-Saxon calendar had two seasons, summer and winter. But the Christian church seems to havehad a calendar with four seasons. So even before the Norman invasion in 1066, you can find documents listing four seasons: lent, summer, harvest, winter. The idea of having two seasons and of having four seasons seem to have coexisted in England for quite a long time—in the 13th century, presumably some of the Anglo-Saxon peasants still counted two seasons, while the Norman aristocracy would have counted four.

Comment: @PeterShor - so the "somer" may actually refer to springtime?

Comment: @Josh61: I think it's pretty clear from the lyrics that *Somer is ycumen in* refers to spring. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumer_Is_Icumen_In#Lyrics_translations) has an argument that it really means *summer*. But they translate it as *the seed is growing and the meadow is blooming and the wood is coming into leaf.* And it talks about lambs, calves, and bullocks (which at that time meant young bulls, and not castrated ones). So I think it means that the concept of a two-season year still survived in parts of England.

Comment: The French variant is *Une hirondelle ne fait pas le printemps* while the Italian one is *una rondine non fa primavera*. Wiktionary upholds the ancient Greek origin [*From a remark by Aristotle (384 BCE - 322 BCE): "One swallow does not a summer make, nor one fine day; similarly one day or brief time of happiness does not make a person entirely happy."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make)

Comment: I really believe that this question deserved more attention, it's a good question and many websites mention the disparity between fact (swallows migrate in spring) and the British proverb. So, who knows, in the future this question/page might attract a lot more visitors.

Comment: It is odd that the seemingly more traditional "...does not a summer make" appears to be a more recent addition, according to Google's Ngram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's a Greek Saying

It appears several sources support the claim that the proverb, **one swallow does not a summer make**,  has its origin in Ancient Greece.

From *Nicomachean Ethics*, Aristotle (384 BCE - 322 BCE) uses the term [ἕαρ](http://translation.sensagent.com/%CE%95%CE%91%CE%A1/el-en/) which is Greek for ‘springtide’ and ‘spring’: ["*One swallow does not make **a spring**, nor does one sunny day; similarly, one day or a short time does not make a man blessed and happy*"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Aristotle#Nicomachean_Ethics)

An alternative version: [*“Moreover, to be happy takes a complete lifetime; **for one swallow does not make spring**, nor does one fine day; and similarly one day or a brief period of happiness does not make a man supremely blessed and happy.”*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0054%3Abekker%20page%3D1098a)

In opposition, the website [BookBrowse](https://www.bookbrowse.com/expressions/detail/index.cfm/expression_number/458/one-swallow-does-not-make-a-summer?) argues that the poetic proverb probably pre-dates Aristotle:

> Many fables have been written based on the proverb including one attributed to Aesop. However, consider that Aesop lived around 600 BC (or at least the legend that became Aesop appears to have originated around this time as there's some uncertainty whether Aesop actually existed), **it would seem that the proverb dates back at least a few hundred years before Aristotle.**
>
> In Aesop's fable, a young man sees a swallow on a warm winter day. Thinking that winter is over, he sells off his woolen coat, and with the money he's made he goes to the bar and drinks. Unfortunately, in the days that follow the temperature drops and the young man, shivering in the cold, realizes that one swallow does not make a summer.

In its article *[The Young Man and the Swallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Man_and_the_Swallow)*, Wikipedia tells us that the proverb was already well-known in England before Aesop's fable, translated in English, appeared in 1600.

> Although the fable was translated into Latin prose during the 15th century, it was not included in European vernacular collections of the time but begins to be recorded in the 16th. Poetic versions are included in French in *Les Fables d'Esope Phrygien, mises en Ryme Francoise* (1542)[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Man_and_the_Swallow) and in Latin by Hieronymus Osius (1564). **In England the fable does not appear in collections before the 17th century, but the proverb, in the form 'One swallow does not make a summer', is recorded a century earlier**. Erasmus includes its Latin version in his Adagia and the proverb is common throughout Europe.

**1539** <sub><sup>R. TAVERNER</sup></sub> tr. Erasmus' Adages 25 “It is not one swalowe that bryngeth in somer. It is not one good qualitie that maketh a man good”

**1546** *[The Proverbs of John Heywood](https://archive.org/stream/proverbsofjohnhe00heywrich#page/120/mode/2up/search/summer)*. The following snippet on p.121 is from an 1874 edition.

> One swallow maketh not summer.
>
> One swallowe prouveth not that summer is neare.

### Why do British (and Spanish) swallows migrate later?

If the French and Italian proverbs *[une hirondelle ne fait pas le printemps](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/une-hirondelle-ne-fait-pas-le-printemps.htm)* and  *[una rondine non fa primavera](http://paroladelgiorno.com/2015/03/25/una-rondine-non-fa-primavera/)* correctly identify *spring* as being the  migratory period, since when do swallows migrate to the British Isles in June and July?

Well, it could be that the term *spring*, the season following winter, was still in its infancy when the proverb came into vogue. In Old English,  the season was known as ***lencten*** "springtime, spring," while *summer* is a much older word.  Etymonline, the online etymology dictionary par excellence, confirms:

> **[spring](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spring)** season following winter, the vernal season, c. 1400, earlier *springing time* (late 14c.), which replaced *[**Lent**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Lent&allowed_in_frame=0)*, the Old English word. […]The notion is of the "spring of the year," when plants begin to rise (as in spring of the leaf, 1520s), from the noun in its old sense of "action or time of rising or springing into existence." It was used of sunrise, the waxing of the moon, rising tides, etc.; compare 14c. spring of dai "sunrise," spring of mone "moonrise," late Old English spring "carbuncle, pustule."

Whereas *[summer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=summer&allowed_in_frame=0)* is derived from Old English *sumor*  and from Proto-Germanic *sumur- (cognates: Old Saxon, Old Norse, Old High German *sumar*, Old Frisian *sumur*, Middle Dutch *somer*, Dutch *zomer*, German *Sommer*)

I'm no poetess, but both *swallow* and *summer* begin with the letter S, and both words have two syllables, and both contain double consonants, so perhaps the two scan better in unison; especially in its 16th century variant. The “original” phrase *looks* more symmetrical,

> *one swallow maketh not summer*

compared to

> *one swallow maketh not Lent*
>   (or)
>   *one swallow maketh not spring*

<sub>P.S. Spanish swallows also appear to travel later compared to their French and Italian cousins:

 - ***una golondrina no hace verano*** ([wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/una_golondrina_no_hace_verano))</sub>

<sub>P.P.S And a special thanks to @Peter Shor who pointed out that Aristotle's original citation had the term *spring*.</sub>

Comment: One note: it [appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Man_and_the_Swallow) that Aristotle actually said "spring".

Comment: @PeterShor wiki got it wrong, well spotted! I merely copy and pasted the citation. But your link directs me to Aesop's fable, not to Aristotle

Comment: It also gives Aristotle's quote in Ancient Greek: μία χελίδὼν ἕαρ ού ποίεῖ. Google translate confirms that ἕαρ means spring.

Comment: Very nice answer. Any idea on why also the "spring" version appears to be a common one in English according to Google Books?

Comment: @Josh61 without a single doubt, the overwhelming majority of English citations are that of the "summer" one. In comparison, the citations containing spring are far fewer, and many of them actually cite Aristotle's quotation and mention the fact that the French/Italian proverbs cite "spring". Of course, I didn't go through each and every single instance but that was my general impression